# Assigning dataframe to dataframe in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

When i assign dataframe to another dataframe, making changes to one dataframe affects another dataframe

Code:

```
interest_margin_data = initial_margin_data
interest_margin_data['spanReq'] = (interest_margin_data['spanReq']*interest_margin_data['currency'].map(interestrate_dict))/(360*100*interest_margin_data['currency'].map(currency_dict))
initial_margin_data['spanReq'] /=  initial_margin_data['currency'].map(currency_dict)
```

The second line changes the values in initial_margin_data as well.
Why is this so? How to affect this?

Comment: Because assigning one DataFrame to a second variable does not automatically create a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.copy` to create a separate dataframe in memory:

```
interest_margin_data = initial_margin_data.copy()
```

It creates a different object in memory, rather than just pointing to the same place.

This is done so if you create a "view" of the dataframe it does not require substantially extra memory. It can index it, and calculate using the source.

In your case however you do not want this.